# append time to log filenames

Tags: shell, date, tcsh

I want to make log_files named as `log_Jan_01_hh:mm:ss`, so the variable time-stamp is defined as `date +"%b_%d_%T"`.
Now if I set the value to a variable:

```
setenv now `date +"%b_%d_%T"`
```

Then `$now` variable does get value update at that moment, so all the time log files have same name.

How can I do something so that `$now` gets it value refreshed at every moment?

Comment: Whereever you're using the filename, use `"log_$(date +"%b_%d_%T")"`.

Comment: I can do `"log_$(date +"%b_%d_%T")"` but it would be easier if I have it in a variable so that I can just use `log_$now`

Comment: No, it won't be "easier".

Comment: @muru I will define that variable in my `~/.cshrc` file, so that when ever I need I can use that variable as `log_$now` whenever I need.
I didn't get the "easier" part in using or typing 
_Whereever you're using the filename, use "log_$(date +"%b_%d_%T")"_
for all time

Comment: Making `$now` have an updated variable won't be easy. Hence, not easier. If you want, create a function `now` and do `log_$(now)`.

Comment: @muru can it be done by adding something in `~/.cshrc_local ~/.cshrc` files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19143/discussion-between-jigargandhi-and-muru).

Comment: @muru `$()` syntax doesn't work in `tcsh`, that's Bourne sytax. In `tcsh`, you can only use backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just store a string in `$now`, and add backticks when you invoke it, you get the current date:

```
[~]% setenv now 'date +"%b_%d_%T"'

[~]% echo $now
date +"%b_%d_%T"

[~]% echo `$now`
"Dec_03_13:09:52"

[~]% echo `$now`
"Dec_03_13:09:54"
```

This is effectively the same as doing:

```
[~]% echo `date +"%b_%d_%T"`
```

There is no way to tell `tcsh` to re-evaluate the command on invoking the variable; you assign a string to `$now`, and `tcsh` has no way of knowing what the command was that generated this string.
Another (possible) solution might be using functions, but `tcsh` lacks those as well...

Comment: @muru, did not read about tcsh. Sorry. I removed my comment.

Comment: When I tried the above series of commands,It didn't go exactly the same 
**INPUT**
`setenv now 'date +"%b_%d_%T"'`
`echo $now`
`echo `$now``

**OUTPUT**
`Dec_03_01:42:36`
`Dec_03_01:42:36: Command not found.`

It did evaluated at first definition.

Comment: @JigarGandhi Not sure what's doing on there ... Maybe you made a typo ... Perhaps you can copy/paste everything you did *exactly* to pastebin, that works better than comments.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I did exactly same. check out my [steps](http://s17.postimg.org/kfrqqqx3j/sna.jpg)

Comment: @JigarGandhi Are you sure you didn't do `set $now = ..` somewhere? Variables from `set` take precedence over `setenv`. Maybe in your `tcshrc`? try using a different variable name (environment variables are often ALL CAPS exactly to present this sort of conflict).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker found the bug. it was in `~/.cshrc_local`.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your crontab, and run it every minute.

```
crontab -e
```

Insert a line like that:

```
* * * * * setenv now 'date +"%b_%d_%T"'
```

Save and quit. Your variable will be updated every minute.

Comment: I cannot edit `crontab` as its in binary format

`-rwsr-xr-x  1 root Wheel 223K Jan 30  2009 /usr/bin/crontab`

Comment: @JigarGandhi You don't edit `/usr/bin/crontab`; it's a command that you execute.

Comment: Re: The actual answer; let us ignore that `setenv` won'twork here, you can't just set en environment variable from a crontab, the is different for every process. This will just set it for the crontab process.

Comment: Is this normal ? I tried to do it above workout, but then I quit.

_**terminal output**_
no crontab for jigarg - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXJ5wytX":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.XXXXJ5wytX

Comment: @JigarGandhi This answer i mistaken anyway, and won't work.